# Search results SharePoint 2013 encode URL space from %20 to %2520 for Office Documents

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, office-web-apps, internet-explorer

I have a problem with my Search Results in Sharepoint 2013, When I try to open an Office document the URL (space) changes from %20 to %2520, (for PDF documents no problem...) so I have an error page :  A potentially Dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%), and in a listView when I try to open office document in the browser IE9, it try to download (PDF opens in the browser)
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the "Double Encoding Bug". You can find a workaround here:

http://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/06/workaround-ms14-022-double-encoding-bug/

Answer (score 0):

The *Double Encoding Bug* has been fixed in the September 2014 CU of SharePoint 2013. Source: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Regressions/sp2013sep2014cu.aspx